# A very detailed post I made some years ago has been deleted. Where is it?

Tags: discussion

I searched for my old question or answer and I found it was no longer on superuser but was archived on this website here with no pictures.

Is it possible to plug a 2.5" drive in wrongly and could I break it? - See more at: http://demo102.phpcaiji.com/article/ffefea-is-it-possible-to-plug-a-2-5-drive-in-wrongly-and-could-i-break-it.html#sthash.kQ3QhIfK.dpuf

I'd be interested if it's still available anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This? [Is it possible to plug a 2.5" drive in wrongly and could I break it?](https://superuser.com/questions/554540/is-it-possible-to-plug-a-2-5-drive-in-wrongly-and-could-i-break-it)

Doesn't appear deleted.

FWIW, I found this by searching your posts: https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A42672+%22is+it+possible%22

Comment: Thanks.. I tried googling some keywords prior to knowing the title and it seemed gone.. And i'm used to superuser  or stackexchange sites closing and deleting questions and not telling the person beforehand, I thought my Q/A had gone that way.

Comment: Would be great if the site had its own search